# Наследование в java и переменные

Tags: java, наследование

Почему в Java 16, выводом для кода

```java
public class C extends A2 {
    public int a = 100;
    public int c = 300;
    
    {
        a = 500;
    }
    
    public void printC() {
        System.out.println("c = " + c);
    }    
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        C c = new C();
        c.printC();
        c.printA2();
        c.a = 600;
        c.printA2();
        System.out.println("c.a = " + c.a);
    }
}

class A2 {
    public int a = 1;
    public void printA2() {
        System.out.println("a = " + a);
    }
}
```

Будет

```
c = 300
a = 1
a = 1
c.a = 600
```

И можно ли через printA2() вывести измененное значение?
Я ожидал увидеть

```
c = 300
a = 500
a = 600
c.a = 600
```

Comment: Используй в таких случаях [дебагер](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80+intellij). Ставишь точку останова на нужный тебе вызов и по шагам шагаешь и смотришь, что происходит под капотом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У класса `С` уже есть поле `а`, унаследованное от `А`.

Уберите строчку

```
public int a = 100;
```

из `C`, и увидите то, что ожидали.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Поразмыслив, такой код сделал то, что я хотел...

```java
public class C extends A2 {
    @Override
    public void printA2() {
        super.a = this.a;
        super.printA2();
    }    
    
    public int a = 100;
    public int c = 300;
    
    {
        a = 500;
    }
    
    public void printC() {
        System.out.println("c = " + c);
    }    
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        C c = new C();
        c.printC();
        c.printA2();
        c.a = 600;
        c.printA2();
        System.out.println("c.a = " + c.a);
    }
}

class A2 {
    public int a = 1;
    public void printA2() {
        System.out.println("a = " + a);
    }
}
```

Но ответ пользователя **Igor** мне понравился больше :)